# what is blocking the readLine() in this case? I tried sending \n or even byte arrays, is it a concurrency issue in my case?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, concurrency, readline

I tried everything stack overflow has to offer on this common readLine problem. (sending \n, flushing out, changing to byte array style, becoming hermit, wrists )

I suspect in this case its a concurrency thing as  Ispent well over 15 hours yesterday confirming that the only thing that isnt working is readline()!

I used loads of other versions like datareader with a byte array and making sure a \n got sent I even sent /ns just in case!

still my issue is the same, and I have ran out of ideas myself to solve the issue and have decided that somewhere, my problem is outside my understanding, just where? its got to be threading right?

I managed to get to read the socket to string that seemed to work so it IS blocking because reading the connection isnt working at all, the readline function is not the only way Ive had it as I said so in my snippets its not as developed as it has been but still the basic issue remains.

Please help, i dont know what the issue is

// So the main class initialises the socket objects and starts them in a thread, these work I get all sorts of flags letting me know that they are

```
void start_sockets() {

            //if this is initiialised as a server and not a client
    if (is_server) {

        while (is_server) {


            try {

                System.out.println("listening for connection");
                Sockject sj = new Sockject(server.accept());
                sock_arr.add(sj);
                System.out.println("server made connection ");

                // once the connection is made the objects is started in a
                // separate thread
                new Thread(sock_arr.get(sock_arr.size() - 1)).start();


            } catch (IOException e) {


            }
        }
    } else {  //else im running a client version of this class

        // if the client socket isnt running in a thread, make it run
        if (!running) {

            new Thread(sj_client).start();

            if (sj_client.sock.isConnected()) {

                System.out.println("client thread connected to "
                        + sj_client.sock.getLocalSocketAddress());
                running = true;
            }
        }
    }
}


    //the inner class creates a socket object and puts it on an array or an object depending if the parent class is initialised to be a server or a client
```

class Sockject implements Runnable {

```
    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;

    // a socket for processing
    Socket sock;

    // the constructor in this case initialises the input and output streams
    Sockject(Socket s) {

        sock = s;
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    this.sock.getInputStream()));

        } catch (IOException e) {

            close sockets
        }
    }

    //tried variasions of this and similar, used data objects and been sennding /ns all over the shop
    void recieve_data() throws IOException {


        if (sock.isConnected()) {

            if ((recieve = in.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println("recieve says " + recieve);
            }
        }
    }

    // sends data to connection if it is cleared to send data
    void send_data(String data) {

        // send data called
        if (clear_to_send == true) {

            out.print(data);
            out.flush();
            clear_to_send = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (threadloop ) {

            try {

                //code defo gets this far and with just send it keeps running forever so its defo recieve data thats the issue
                send_data(send);


                recieve_data();// <---I HATE YOU

            } catch (IOException e) {



            }

        }
    }

}
```

}

Now all of the above is ran in an instance of this class, in a thread of this class here these temporary functions are ran and are neversuccesfull

```
void servrecievex(){

    System.out.println("NEVER GETS THIS FA THOUGH DOES IT");
    for(int a = 0; a < net_flow.sock_arr.size(); a++){

        if(net_flow.sock_arr.get(a).sock.isConnected()){
        System.out.println("server recieve function");
        net_flow.sj_client.clear_to_send = true;
    net_flow.sock_arr.get(a).send_data("www  /n \n");

    System.out.println("RECIVEIFY!!!");
    }
    }
}

void clientsendx() {

    net_flow.sj_client.clear_to_send = true;
    net_flow.sj_client.send_data(Integer.toString(player1.posx) + "\n");
    System.out.println("client sent stuff");
}
```

Comment: Why not `new Thread(sj).start();` instead of `sock_arr.get(sock_arr.size() - 1)` ?

Comment: Are you really sure that data got send?  Do you know for sure that `clear_to_send` was actually `true` when you called `send_data`?  (Looking at the code ... I'm not.)  Have you tried using a debugger???

Comment: I never really used the debugger I have a slow ass way of working through my code, I talk to a little duck...but yeah it does sendify I was trying to cut a lot of irrelivant stuff out, thats still something I need to work on despite all the good explanations here

Comment: Yea well.  Using a debugger in this case will allow you to be a lot more sure about what is happening (assuming this isn't a concurrency problem.)

Comment: Yeap, it wasnt the problem I ever thought it was -_- FIFTEEN HOURS FIFTEEN....ARGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH                                                            Mr Flibble is going as much as it breaks my heart.

Comment: Okay from looking at my other questions I can see im not actually underbraining im either overbraining or missbraining and the true lesson learned, or better yet  the real problem that is solved is that I am not thinking like a programmer, im thinking of asking for help planning and thinking about code in stack overflow, I want people to link to it rather than having their problem solved, because, there are a lot of good brainers out there who arent going to be more succesfull than underbrainers, because underbrainers digest small chunks at a time like they should.

Comment: Duck typing I understand, but I prefer a debugger to a duck when problems arise.